# 重複したアカウントをマージしたい

Tags: サポート, アカウント

すいません、完全にユーザーとしての質問です。

日本語版のStackOverflowを使うのに新しいアカウントを作ってしまいました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/24/junichi-ito

しかし、英語版のStackOverflowアカウントがあるので日本語版でもこちらを使いたいです。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/85/junichi-ito

アカウントをマージすることはできますか？それともどちらかを削除するしかありませんか？

Answer (score 3):

「お問い合わせ」から連絡すればマージしてくれます。

マージ方法の指定のためにちょっと準備が必要なので、詳しくは[ヘルプセンターの記事へ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)。

Comment: ありがとうございます！が、予期せずアカウントがマージされてしまったようです。。

85のアカウントでログインして、ログイン方法を24のgmailアカウントでログインするように変更したら24のアカウントが85のアカウントにマージされたみたいです。

ちなみにログイン方法を変更したのはマージするつもりではなく、昔のメールアドレスを現在メインで使っているメールアドレスに変更するつもりでログイン方法を変更しました。

ちょっと変な気もしますが、今のところこれで問題ないようなので良しとします。